# is __vptr shared by all the objects of a class in C++?

Tags: c++

When we made function as virtual in a class, compiler will set a static array at compile time which contains of addresses of all virtual functions and when we create an object for that class, __vptr is created and it will contain the starting address of the virtual table. But why can't __vptr is shared by all the objects of the same class?

Comment: How would you find the vptr at runtime?

Comment: How does the runtime know what object is of which class? the vptr give an object its runtime identity, from a virtual function point of view.

Comment: The whole point of the __vptr is that you know that each object in a class hierarchy has one, and that its value changes depending on its place in the hierarchy. Even if all the objects of a single class have the same __vptr, not all the objects of a class hierarchy has the same one.